# Counting the number of pixels in blocks of an image

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

in the attached code, the programme divides the image into blocks and attempts to count the number of white pixels in each row of each block. The original image is below.

[image]

The problem is that the code effectively counts the pixels in the whole image by the amount of times I divide the image up and not each individual block.

If anyone has any improvements on how to make this programme identify each block of the image (I think that is the main problem) then it would solve this problem.

Thanks!

::::EDIT::::

I have solved my problem however that comes with a new challenge (yay). The result of this code gives an output of:

```
rows =

   148
   217
   475
   521
   567
   724


thickness =

    69
   258
    46
    46
   157

plotindex = 2,   c=2, r=1

rows =

   148
   217
   475
   596
   650
   716


thickness =

    69
   258
   121
    54
    66
```

**I want to store the "thickness" values in an array ( the number of black pixels that seperate white pixels in a column) soI can process this data later.**

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
fontSize = 20;

rgbImage = imread('http://i.imgur.com/gnmVFLq.png');
%just any image for reference


% Display image full screen.
imshow(rgbImage);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
drawnow;
% Get the dimensions of the image.  numberOfColorBands should be = 3.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage)

%==========================================================================
% The first way to divide an image up into blocks is by using mat2cell().
blockSizeR = 844; % Rows in block.
blockSizeC = 665; % Columns in block.

% Figure out the size of each block in rows.
% Most will be blockSizeR but there may be a remainder amount of less than that.
wholeBlockRows = floor(rows / blockSizeR);
blockVectorR = [blockSizeR * ones(1, wholeBlockRows), rem(rows, blockSizeR)];
% Figure out the size of each block in columns.
wholeBlockCols = floor(columns / blockSizeC);
blockVectorC = [blockSizeC * ones(1, wholeBlockCols), rem(columns, blockSizeC)];

% Create the cell array, ca. 
% Each cell (except for the remainder cells at the end of the image)
% in the array contains a blockSizeR by blockSizeC by 3 color array.
% This line is where the image is actually divided up into blocks.
if numberOfColorBands > 1
    % It's a color image.
    ca = mat2cell(rgbImage, blockVectorR, blockVectorC, numberOfColorBands);
else
    ca = mat2cell(rgbImage, blockVectorR, blockVectorC);
end

% Now display all the blocks.
plotIndex = 1;
numPlotsR = size(ca, 1);
numPlotsC = size(ca, 2);

for r = 1 : numPlotsR;
    for c = 1 : numPlotsC;


        fprintf('plotindex = %d,   c=%d, r=%d\n', plotIndex, c, r);
        % Specify the location for display of the image.
        subplot(numPlotsR, numPlotsC, plotIndex);
        % Extract the numerical array out of the cell
        rgbBlock = ca{r,c};
        imshow(rgbBlock); % Could call imshow(ca{r,c}) if you wanted to.
        [rowsB columnsB numberOfColorBandsB] = size(rgbBlock);
        % Make the caption the block number.
        caption = sprintf('Block #%d of %d\n%d rows by %d columns', ...
            plotIndex, numPlotsR*numPlotsC, rowsB, columnsB);
        title(caption);
        drawnow;
        % Increment the subplot to the next location.

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        imBinary = double(im2bw(rgbBlock)); %//Convert to binary, 
                              %// then make double for sum
histogram = sum(imBinary,2); %// Compute row-wise histograms
stem(1:size(imBinary,1), histogram); %// Histogram of white pixels
xlabel('Row number');
ylabel('White pixel count');
grid;


diffs = diff([0; histogram]);
threshold = 100; %// Threshold that determines whether it is black or white
rows = find(diffs >= threshold)

thickness = diff(rows)


        plotIndex = plotIndex + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: `blockSizeR = 844` is already going beyond the no. of rows for this image.

Comment: have you considered using [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)?

Comment: @divakar oh, forgot to change that parameter. The original image is this http://i.imgur.com/lc8ESac.png, but the output is still the same

Comment: Can you use a small input data (maybe 3D) and tell us the expected output? The code you have is outputting a lot of data and figures and it's confusing what's important and what's not.